# Use a selection from an auto-complete to filter a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6lx0aQUz8EgvSiluAgyd?p=preview) similar to what I'm trying to do.

I would like to provide an auto-complete list for a user to filter the table.

The filter works fine while the user is typing, but if the user selects an option from the auto-complete list, then the filter stops filtering.

For example...

- The plunker shows a list of 30 badges a SO users can earn.
- I type 'Au' into the text box; the filter reduces the list to two badges
- I press the down arrow button, then enter.
- 'Autobiographer' is auto-completed into the textbox, but the list still shows two items

How can I select an auto-complete option and have it filter the list?

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.9" data-semver="1.3.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', []);

      app.factory('badges', ['$http', function($http) {
          return $http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?page=1&order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow')
            .success(function(data) {
              return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              return err;
            });
      }]);

      app.factory('badgesagain', ['$http', function($http) {
          return $http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?page=1&order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow')
            .success(function(data) {
              return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              return err;
            });
      }]);  

      app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'badges', 'badgesagain', function($scope, badges, badgesagain){

          badgeNames = [];
          badges.then(function(response){

            for(var i=0; i < response.data.items.length; i++){
              badgeNames[i] = response.data.items[i].name;
            }

          });

          $scope.availableTags = badgeNames;
          $scope.complete = function () {
            console.log('running');
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: $scope.availableTags
            });
          };

          badges.success(function(data) {
            $scope.badgeList = data['items'];
          });

    }]);
  </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
      <input id="tags" ng-keyup="complete()" ng-model="c.name"/>
    </div>
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="badge in badgeList | filter:c ">
        {{ badge.name }}
      </li>
    </ol>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
      <input id="tags" ng-keyup="complete()" ng-model="c.name"/>
    </div>
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="badge in badgeList | filter:c ">
        {{ badge.name }}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing angular and jquery is asking for trouble.

Consider an angular solution like [allmighty-autocomplete](https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

Mixing jQuery and angular is not ideal in the long run. You are likely to encounter issues like this where angular is not aware of the changes made by the jquery plugin. That's why it's recommended to use a angular plugin such as [angular-bootstrap typeahead component](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

However, we can fix your issue by letting angular know once an item is selected. We can achieve this using the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) callback from jQuery autocomplete.

See this example:

```
$scope.complete = function () {
  console.log('running');
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: $scope.availableTags,
    select : function(evt, ui) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.c.name = ui.item.value;
      });
    }
  });
};
```

[Plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/c2JoDN6ci8x5dmfqDJQS?p=preview)